# Installation of "Mono for Android" does not install anything without any error reported

Tags: android, mono, installation, xamarin.android

I am trying to install Mono for Android on Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit. Setup is just checking for components and then tells: "You're Ready" "It appears that your system is already set up to use Mono for Android!". It does not install anything!

These lines are found in log:

```
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.229] [Info] Determining list of software items to install.
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.230] [Info] Component detection starting
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.230] [Debug] Processing update nodes from the manifest.
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.230] [Info] Waiting for detection to finish
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.231] [Info] Detection complete
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.231] [Info] Component detection complete
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.231] [Debug] Download service starting.
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.232] [Info] Component detection task completed successfully
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.232] [Debug] Creating and initializing software item 'Java JDK'
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.232] [Debug] Creating and initializing software item 'Android SDK'
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.233] [Debug] Creating and initializing software item 'GTK#'
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.233] [Debug] Creating and initializing software item 'MonoDevelop'
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.233] [Debug] Creating and initializing software item 'Mono for Android, VisualStudio and MonoDevelop'
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.334] [Debug] Detection completed.
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.335] [Info] No software needs to be installed.
[2012-06-21 05:17:43.335] [Info] Status: successful
```

I do not have some of the components (like "Android SDK") installed on my machine, so why it says "No software needs to be installed"? Do I need to install all the SDKs by myself (what will be different from "http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/installation/Installation_for_Windows")?
Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue they're working on that seems to happen for Windows 7 64bit systems. You can view the [bug report here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5695). According to the bug, it sounds like running the installer a few times might help get it to finish. If you have any more information that might be helpful for them in reproducing/fixing the problem, I'd definitely suggest logging it in the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be installer issue. Get mono-android-4.6.07004.msi from the web and copy it to C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\Temp\MonoForAndroid\downloads. Run the mentioned .msi file from there. After it's finished, run Xamarin installation again. It will take some time for Xamarin installer to finish. This should work.